# Corona SDK rotation

Tags: rotation, coronasdk

I'm working on a project that involves a clock, and a set_alarm mechanism that works by dragging a rotating pointer (clock is classic like analog with pointers, not digital) that is attached to the center of the clock, so by rotating pointer (that sets alarm) you can set the alarm. Here is the source:

```
local function rotateObj2(event)
    local t = event.target
    local phase = event.phase

    if (phase == "began") then
            display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( t )
            t.isFocus = true

            -- Store initial position of finger
            t.x1 = event.x
            t.y1 = event.y

    elseif t.isFocus then
            if (phase == "moved") then
                    animateAlarm = true
                    t.x2 = event.x
                    t.y2 = event.y

                    angle1 = 180/math.pi * math.atan2(t.y1 - t.y , t.x1 - t.x)
                    angle2 = 180/math.pi * math.atan2(t.y2 - t.y , t.x2 - t.x)
                    print("angle1 = "..angle1)
                    rotationAmt = angle1 - angle2

                    --rotate it
                    t.rotation = t.rotation - rotationAmt
                    print ("t.rotation = "..t.rotation)

                    t.x1 = t.x2
                    t.y1 = t.y2
                    alarm.rotation = t.rotation
                    setAlarm.rotation = t.rotation
                    print ("setAlarm.rotation = "..t.rotation)
                    if(alarm.rotation >=0)then
                        local hourValue = math.floor(t.rotation/30)
                        local minuteValue = math.floor(t.rotation*2)
                        local hour = hourValue
                        local minute = minuteValue  

                        if(minuteValue>=720 and minuteValue<780)then 
                            minute = minuteValue-720
                        elseif(minuteValue>=660 and minuteValue<720)then 
                            minute = minuteValue-660
                        elseif(minuteValue>=600 and minuteValue<660)then 
                            minute = minuteValue-600
                        elseif(minuteValue>=540 and minuteValue<600)then 
                            minute = minuteValue-540
                        elseif(minuteValue>=480 and minuteValue<540)then 
                            minute = minuteValue-480
                        elseif(minuteValue>=420 and minuteValue<480)then 
                            minute = minuteValue-420
                        elseif(minuteValue>=360 and minuteValue<420)then 
                            minute = minuteValue-360
                        elseif(minuteValue>=300 and minuteValue<360)then 
                            minute = minuteValue-300
                        elseif(minuteValue>=240 and minuteValue<300)then 
                            minute = minuteValue-240
                        elseif(minuteValue>=180 and minuteValue<240)then 
                            minute = minuteValue-180
                        elseif(minuteValue>=120 and minuteValue<180)then 
                            minute = minuteValue-120
                        elseif(minuteValue>=60 and minuteValue<120)then 
                            minute = minuteValue-60
                        end

                        if (hour < 10) then hour = "0" .. hour end
                        if (minute < 10) then minute = "0" .. minute end


                        hourField.text = hour
                        minuteField.text = minute

                    end
            elseif (phase == "ended") then
                    display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( nil )
                    t.isFocus = false


                    print ("ENDEDsetAlarm.rotation = "..setAlarm.rotation)
            end
    end

    -- Stop further propagation of touch event
    return true
end
```

The problem is that when I try to define alarm clock value (like 03.45) it's ok. I transform the rotation of the pointer as you can see. But, if the rotation goes below -90 or over 270 i dont get results. That's because i did not define what to do with that (-rotation)

PROBLEM:

after some time, the rotation shifts. So i dont have rotation = 0 to 270 and -90 to 0, but -90 to -360+(-90) = -450;

sometimes it becomes from 60 to 360+60=420

WTF IS THAT?! =(

help please, i can't get around that, Because these "shifts" seem to happen randomly(or I just cant get why they happen)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: where dx and dy are equal to the change in x and the change in y

```
angle = ((math.atan2(dx,dy)*180 / math.pi) - 180) * -1
```

This will give you a positive value between 0 and 360 no matter which direction you turn or how many rotations you make.